# Disable Quarkus Camel start up information/banner

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus 3.2.6 with Apache Camel 4.0.0. When it starts up various start up information is logged. How do I disable this? I've already set `quarkus.banner.enabled=false` but the information persists. Example output

```java
Bootstrap runtime: org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime
Apache Camel (Main) 4.0.0 is starting
Created default XPathFactory org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@1eb6e1c
Apache Camel 4.0.0 (camel-1) is starting
Routes startup (started:1)
    Started Test (direct://input)
Apache Camel 4.0.0 (camel-1) started in 87ms (build:0ms init:0ms start:87ms)
test-lambda 1.0.0 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.2.6.Final) started in 4.956s.
Profile prod activated.
Installed features: [amazon-lambda, camel-aws2-lambda, camel-core, camel-direct, camel-http, camel-log, camel-stax, camel-xpath, camel-xslt, camel-xslt-saxon, cdi, logging-json]
```

EDIT: So far I've tried disabling them via config. Below but this did not work.

```java
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus".level=OFF
quarkus.log.category."org.apa.cam".level=OFF
```

Comment: Log category 'org.apa.cam' is not correct. It's just a shortened version that you see output to the console. The full category name is org.apache.camel.

Comment: Of' course! Thank you!

Comment: If you pop this as an answer I can mark is as correct for you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no configuration option to specifically disable those startup messages. But you can tweak the log levels with configuration properties.

```
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus".level=OFF
quarkus.log.category."org.apache.camel".level=OFF
```

Note that will disable **all** log messages from those categories.